# Trigonometric ratios

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I'm stuck with a problem. Given is a triangle $\Delta ABC$ with $\angle A = 35°, BC=3$ and $AC=5$.

I need to find the two possible values for $\angle C$. I only managed to found one angle. I did the following:

$\LARGE\frac{BC}{\sin(\angle A)}=\frac{AC}{\sin(\angle B)}=\frac{AB}{\sin(\angle C)}$

This makes:

$\LARGE\frac{3}{\sin(35°)}=\frac{5}{\sin(\angle B)}=\frac{AB}{\sin(\angle C)}$

Conclusion: $\sin(\angle B)=\frac{5\sin(35°)}{3} \rightarrow \angle B=72.93°$ and $\angle C=180-\angle A-\angle B = 72.07°$. However, this is only one of the two solutions. I need to find the other solution, but I have no idea what to do.

Comment: $\sin(180^o-\theta)=sin(\theta)$

Comment: Use $$\cos A=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$$ to find $AB=c$

Then use the other hint

Comment: Thanks @frank000. That was really useful. I did $\angle C_2 = 180 - (180 - \angle B) - \angle A = 37.93°$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the equation
$3^3=5^2+c^2-10c\cos(35^{\circ})$ and solve this equation for $c$